# Testing AngularJS controller /w karma-jasmine: 'jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime)' undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

**Testing setup:**

"karma-jasmine": "^0.2.3",

"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",

**The test:**

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: Ctrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var Ctrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Ctrl = $controller('Ctrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });

    jasmine.clock().install();
  }));

  it('scope.<day> should be correct', function () {

    var baseTime = new Date(2014,10,24);
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

    expect(scope.sunday).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.monday).toBe(true);    
    expect(scope.tuesday).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.wednesday).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.thursday).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.friday).toBe(false);
    expect(scope.saturday).toBe(false);

  });
});
```

**Gives this:**

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Controller: Ctrl scope. should be correct FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime)')**

Comment: There's no mention of `.mockDate()` in the [current Jasmine documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). Googling for `jasmine mockDate` doesn't give me any joy. Where have you found this API?

Comment: There's a section "Mocking the date" in the Jasmine 2.1 document http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date

Comment: Then maybe try using `karma-jasmine` version `0.3.x` and including that particular version of `jasmine`.

Comment: Oh... okay thanks. I thought karma-jasmine comes with 2.1 version. So this mockDate is not included in 2.0.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `karma-jasmine` version `0.3.x`, which doesn't include `jasmine` on its own. Then specify the version of `jasmine` containing your required functionality.